# Typescript - define a type for external AMD Module

Tags: typescript

I am loading a non-typescript amd module (written in javascript, not compiled from ts) inside a typescript module using require:

```
var worker = require('worker');
```

the worker module exports several constructor-functions.

now I want to make some type definitions (for example as the backbone.d.ts)

```
module WorkerModule {
    interface IResult {
        amount(): number;
    }
    interface IWorker {
        work();
        getResult(): IResult;
    }
    interface OtherWorker extends IWorker {
        workMore();
    }
}
```

How can I tell TSC that worker is a WorkerModule.
thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can type your worker variable:

```
var worker: IWorker = require('worker');
```

This will provide type-checking on the `worker` variable.

Comment: thanks, that works, but I just realized what I need is a bit different... the worker module exports several classes so I want the var worker be of some type of a module... I'll edit the question.

Comment: You should still be good to go: `var worker: WorkerModule = require('worker');`

Comment: thank you. so stupid question after all... i always tried with declare for the worker variable. thanks

Comment: @DeyyyFF there are no stupid questions! I only know the answer because at some point I have asked the same question.